# ImportError: No module named flask_login even though I have it installed

Tags: python

I'm new at this and have no idea of what I'm doing wrong:
I have installed the flask_login module with

```
pip install flask_login
```

It apparently worked: if see it installed in c:\users\~\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

And when I use `pip list`, I can see it listed as `Flask-Login (0.4.0)`

Despite of this, when I try to run `from flask_login import LoginManager`, I'm getting `ImportError: No module named flask_login`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running the code with the python3.6 version ?

Comment: @PRMoureu I'm running it with the 3.6 version, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.

For some reason, Anaconda installed Python 2.7 in a path that was colliding with the one I use normally (w/ Python 3). Once I uninstalled Python 2.7, everything worked fine.

For some reason, only flask_login was being affected. My other flask_** libraries were working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to solve using sudo:

```sh
sudo pip install flask_login
```

I think import errors are so common in flask because flask users normally work in virtual environments. Running pip install inside a VE or outside leads to different installations in different paths and can cause confusion. `sudo` installation works globally and can be a solution if you don't need a certain dependency in a specific VE.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are experiencing this in a Python environment with Apache2 and [`mod_wsgi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_wsgi): you have to restart the Apache2 server after installing new Python modules, as otherwise Apache2 will not "see" them even though the Python path is correct. So (assuming Debian / Ubuntu Linux):

```
service apache2 restart
```

Of course, this issue could happen with any module not being found, not just with `flask_login`. It just happened to me with `flask_login`, which is why I'm here …

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS code. In the .venv there was another copy of flask_login so basically just check if another copy of flask_login exists within your lib